# How to include my Javascript file and/or jQuery in my HTML web page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, alert

I have:

1. `controller/reports_controller.rb`
2. `views/reports/index.html.erb`
3. `assets/reports.js`

I have an image in `index.html.erb`:

```
<div class="main_mark">
   <img src="/assets/welcome_main.png" alt="main" class="main_mark_image" />
</div>
```

I want to print an message to the screen (alert message) when the user presses the image. so I want to write a function in `reports.js` that print the message.

`reports.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".main_mark_image").click(function () {
        alert("alon");
    });
});
```

but I think I have to relate between the java script the the html.

any help appreciated!

Comment: Have you linked your `assets/repors.js` and the neccessary jQuery library?

Comment: no, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using an external script you need to tell your HTML file:

```
<script src="assets/reports.js"></script>
```

The above assumes that your 'assets' folder is in the same folder as your index. You also need to include the jQuery library. It's available for download or you can use Google's:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or, for jQuery UI:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would suggest you to use your `reports.js` file by including it in your `application.js` manifest file . This way you will use the benefits of asset-pipeline in Rails 3.2 . Just add this : `//= require reports.js` to your `application.js` before `require_tree .`, and then you should remove `<script src="assets/reports.js"></script>` from your html.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<img src="/assets/welcome_main.png" onclick="alert('alon');" alt="main" class="main_mark_image" />
```

Comment: thank you, but I want to define it in the java script (I want to write a big function.. the alert was an example)..